# What R package is suited to identifying words that are positively correlated with a binary response variable

Tags: r, dplyr, text-mining, tidytext, qdap

I have a tibble that has to three columns:

1. wine - Name of the wine
2. wine_description - Words describing wine (punctuation has been stripped out)
3. target - 0 or 1 variable 1 = Top Rated Wine, 0 = Not Top Rated Wine

What R package might I use if I were interested in identifying words that tend to be present with top-rated wine (the target variable = 1)

I came across Text Mining in R [Text Mining with R](https://www.tidytextmining.com/sentiment.html), but this appears to be more about sentiment analysis which seems close to what I'm trying to achieve, but perhaps a bit off the mark. Any suggestions would be welcomed.

I am working under the assumption that once I've completed some basic analysis I will be able to incorporate that into a logistic regression.

Answer (score 2):

You can use the [tidymodels](https://www.tidymodels.org/) framework for this kind of modeling, using the [textrecipes](https://tidymodels.github.io/textrecipes/) package for data preprocessing. You'll end up with modeling that looks something like this.

```
## ══Workflow════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════
## Preprocessor: Recipe
## Model: logistic_reg()
## 
## ── Preprocessor ────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────
## 5 Recipe Steps
## 
## ● step_tokenize()
## ● step_stopwords()
## ● step_tokenfilter()
## ● step_tfidf()
## ● step_normalize()
## 
## ── Model ───────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────
## Logistic Regression Model Specification (classification)
## 
## Main Arguments:
##   penalty = tune()
##   mixture = 1
## 
## Computational engine: glmnet
```

Check out [this recent tutorial](https://juliasilge.com/blog/animal-crossing/) for more details.

Comment: didn't you write the book on tidy text analysis.  Thanks for the reply.

Answer (score 1):

A minimal working example would be nice. As far as I can see, all you need is a package to turn your data into a document-feature matrix (dfm), using your wine_description variable as the text field. I like [Quanteda](https://quanteda.io/) for doing that.

Logistic regression with the dfm as predictors would then be one way to identify which words are used to describe top-rated wines.